# Mysql, selecting users in a age range

Tags: mysql

Basic query question but can't seem to get this right. I'm trying to find users that are 11 or 12 years old. DOB is stored as a timestamp

timestamp for "11 years ago" is 956485529

timestamp for "12 years ago" is 924863129

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` < 956485529 AND `dob` > 924863129
```

Seems to only return users that are 11 years old, and not the 12 year olds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the data type of `dob` column?

Comment: if possible use the TIMESTAMP datatype

Answer (score 2):

I read that you can change your **dob** type.
Ok, so if you change it to DATETIME (and modify the values in that column to store date of birth as a DATETIME) you could try this:

```
select * FROM users  
WHERE (dob>DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 13 YEAR)) 
  AND (dob<=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 11 YEAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` < 956485529 AND `dob` > 924863129
```

it just return 11 years old users, because of:

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(924863129), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(924863129) | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| 1999-04-23 18:25:29      | 2011-04-23 22:06:50 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(956485529), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(956485529) | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| 2000-04-23 18:25:29      | 2011-04-23 22:07:19 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

today is 2011-04-23! 
2011-04-23 - 1999-04-23 = 12!

so you should write you query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` < 956485529 AND `dob` >= 924863129
```

hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `OR` like you said because dob column **cannot have at the same time two different values.**

```
`dob` < 956485529 AND `dob` > 924863129
```

Or you can try to convert timestamp to year:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') = 2009;
```

and play with this (of course, adapting your query)

Comment: I don't think this works: if 'dob`<924863129 user can be one years old too. Am I right?

Comment: This query returns all my users including those over 12 years old.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use the BETWEEN condition:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` BETWEEN 924863129 AND 956485529
```

Also, i'd recommend the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) datatype. With that, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `dob` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 YEAR)
```

More examples are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I can change the data type of the DOB column no probs

Comment: do that :) varchar is bad for dates

Comment: The BETWEEN query only returns 11 year olds, not 12 year olds.